# Удаление символов, выбраных через regexp в bash

Tags: linux, bash

Всем привет, у меня есть вот такое регулярное выражение: `/-\w?[0-9](.*)/g`
Могу ли я с помощью sed или другими способами в bash удалить из файла символы выбранные этим регулярным выражением?

```
sed -r 's/{{/-\w?[0-9](.*)/g}}/{{}}/g' {{filename}}
```

пыталась сделать так и множеством других вариаций, но ничего не получается

Comment: Откуда в sed-е взялись фигурные скобки?

Comment: Не знаю) Нашла где-то на просторах рунета.

Comment: `/` и `/g` это часть регулярного выражения? или просто флаги?